# Suggestion: No reputation accounts

Tags: feature-request, reputation

I sometimes feel that people up/down vote based on the users reputation and I also see a few people saying "it's about knowledge sharing - not reputation". So I suggest allowing people to turn off their reputation.

A user would be able to "turn off" reputation. While in this mode, their rep isn't displayed and their incoming up/down votes are not counted. (If they downvote, this will deduct from their hidden rep).

Permissions and privileges will remain unchanged.

[Personally, I want 200 rep to tone down adverts. After that - I don't care about rep]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[decidedly off-topic]
And I would like some sort of "**Ghost Sunday**". Maybe as one-time social experiment.

I don't believe it's significant, but there is certainly a lot of campvoting on SO and users inevitably tend to have preferences on people they know. Therefore it might be interesting to have the display of usernames, reputation and votes disabled for a day. -> This would most likely skew the voting process, but eventually in a judgement-on-content-only way.

Answer (score 4):

Immunity from being downvoted? That'll go well...

Comment: Wouldn't say immunity, but would suggest some sort of "Im not here for the rep'" setting.