# Is it possible to turn off "reputation score" notifications?

Tags: support, reputation, user-interface, notifications

I have no problem with inbox notifications, but the reputation score notifications distract me a lot (the ones that tell you: "+5" if someone thumbs up your question).

After looking through the settings, it seems there is no option to turn off these notifications, but I might be wrong and simply don't know where to look.

1. Is there a way to turn off the reputation score notifications via the settings on the site?
2. If not, is there some way to do it via a third-party tool such as an adblocker browser extension?

Comment: Why would you turn it off

Comment: @Squareoot, why would you ask that question

Comment: You could tweak this a bit: https://stackapps.com/questions/3105/hide-all-pointless-user-data-avatar-badges-and-reputation

Comment: This is desirable because I don't need to be notified every time my reputation increases. It's a distraction that encourages being addicted to gains in reputation as opposed to productivity.

Comment: You might like this site's **no reputation** feature (MathOverflow): [Viewing reputation and badges is now opt-in and compatible with the new front page](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/5218/122794) (probably still notified?), and these calls to scrap rep: [Why is a users rep value visible to all?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/259107/282094) and a very old one: [Suggestion: No reputation accounts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/70974/282094)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [uBlock Origin](https://github.com/gorhill/uBlock) ([Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ublock-origin/cjpalhdlnbpafiamejdnhcphjbkeiagm?hl=en), [Safari](https://github.com/el1t/uBlock-Safari), [Edge](https://microsoftedge.microsoft.com/addons/detail/ublock-origin/odfafepnkmbhccpbejgmiehpchacaeak)  and others).

Add this filter to ['my filters'](https://github.com/gorhill/uBlock/wiki/Dashboard:-My-filters) (matches all of the [Stack Exchange Q/A site domains and their subdomains](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81379/can-we-have-a-list-of-all-the-stack-exchange-domains-somewhere-for-firewall-pur/81383#81383)):

```
stackexchange.com,askubuntu.com,mathoverflow.net,serverfault.com,stackoverflow.com,stackapps.com,superuser.com##._positive.js-unread-count.indicator-badge
```

---

A manual method which has to be repeated for all SE domains and subdomains:

1. Right-click on the `+#` green badge, then choose
   ‘Block element’.
2. Click the first cosmetic filter in the list.

   If you don't currently have a badge to right-click on, you can paste this into the text field.

   ```
    ##._positive.js-unread-count.indicator-badge
   ```
3. Create.

[image: uBlock Origin filter]

Comment: If created from this page, the rule only applies to `meta.stackexchange.com`. It's recommend to create a rule for [all Stack Exchange domains](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81379/can-we-have-a-list-of-all-the-stack-exchange-domains-somewhere-for-firewall-pur/81383#81383) in the uBlock Origin's 'my filters' page.